# launch4j exe can't find jre

Tags: java, linux, windows, launch4j

Issues with launch4j

Program consists on one uber jar via maven-shade plugin and a Data/
Runs fine on any jre7 machine, windows or linux

However I've been unable to get launch4j to work.

launch4j config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>pllsolver-0.2alpha.jar</jar>
  <outfile>pllsolver-0.2alpha.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle>NO JRE FOUND</errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir></chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon>sicr.ico</icon>
  <jre>
    <path>jre7</path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <minVersion></minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
  <splash>
    <file>sicr.bmp</file>
    <waitForWindow>false</waitForWindow>
    <timeout>5</timeout>
    <timeoutErr>true</timeoutErr>
  </splash>
  <messages>
  </messages>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Then to build, on windows, I try this:

```
PS K:\test> set PATH="K:\test\jre7\bin\"
PS K:\test> ..\launch4j\launch4jc.exe .\config.xml
launch4j: Compiling resources
launch4j: Linking
launch4j: Wrapping
launch4j: Successfully created K:\test\.\pllsolver-0.2alpha.exe
PS K:\test> .\pllsolver-0.2alpha.exe
PS K:\test>
```

It's at this point that I get a nice little window about how it failed to find the JRE.

Java is in
K:\test\jre7\bin\java.exe
My jar is
K:\test\pllsolver-0.2alpha.jar

Additionally, I don't know if this will be an issue yet, but the executable and the Data/ need to be in the same directory.  I'm planning to do better pathing later but I don't have a clear understanding of Windows ENV variables.

Comment: Okay, I added %JAVA_HOME% set to the jre directory, and added %JAVA_HOME%\bin\ to %PATH%

Then I tried <jre><path>%JAVA_HOME%</path>...</jre> with the same poor results. I am lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a bit late but maybe it can still help you ...

One thing which works for sure with launch4j and JRE is to bundle the JRE in the folder of your application.

To do so:

- create a path 'jre' in the folder with your '*.exe'
- copy a JRE in this folder (this jre has to fit the 'min'/'max' conditions you have set)
- set '<path>/jre</path>' inside the <jre> configuration of your '.xml'

... this should work

Comment: An exe created this way would work independently, right? ie when not in the same folder as the jre

Comment: ... right! you just have to set the path to the jre in your launch4J configuration file

Comment: launch4j 3.14: This don't work. ./jre if in same folder ../jre if you are in 1 step deeper (work like linux)

Answer (score 3):

I struggled around with the JRE setting using launch4j 3.12 (2020) and OpenJDK and got also the message "no java runtime found".
My target, was to use OpenJDK (https://adoptopenjdk.net/)
Two ways were successful:

1. Install OpenJDK, with the JavaSoft (Oracle) registry keys activated and select the "only use public JREs" launch4j-option.
2. Install OpenJDK, with the JAVA_HOME option set, and set the "bundled jre path" in the JRE tab to %JAVA_HOME% (xml content: %JAVA_HOME%)
   With this you are able to use different JRE for different applications setting the JAVA_HOME variable for each of the differently.

Comment: %JAVA_HOME% worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me. The `%PATH%` was missing

```
<jre>
    <path>%JAVA_HOME%;%PATH%</path>
    <requiresJdk>false</requiresJdk>
    <requires64Bit>false</requires64Bit>
    <minVersion></minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
  </jre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be that launch4j is looking for the JRE path relative to its 'outfile' location.

Solutions:

- You can use an absolute path e.g. 'C:\loc\of\jre'
- Put your JRE in your 'outfile' directory and set the JRE path relatively e.g. 'jre'
- Treat the JRE path as relative to the 'outfile' directory e.g. '....\somefolder\jre'

My launch4j version: 3.14